# Is the following idea rigorous?

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I was thinking about how to determine if two functions $f,g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ are linearly independent. For example, $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^5$ then there is no way that these two functions are linearly dependent. However, for much more complicated functions, the linear independence cannot be easily determined (at least in my opinion). Therefore, I need to express these functions as linear combinations of their basis.

My primary idea is to expand a function by its Taylor series, and thus $f(x)$ would be an element of degree $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$. The function could be written as a vector
$$\left\langle f(0),f'(0),\frac{f''(0)}{2!},\dots\right\rangle$$
Therefore, if we have two functions $f,g$, then the linear independence can be quickly determined by checking if there exists a pair $(c_1,c_2)$ s.t. $\forall n$,
$$c_1{f^{(n)}(0)}+c_2{g^{(n)}(0)}=0$$
Here are some doubts of mine:

(1) Can we determine an explicit basis for $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$?

(2) Can we check the linear independence of two $\infty$-dimensional vectors?

(3) Is my idea correct?

Thanks in advance. Please don't be too harsh if this is a stupid idea.

Comment: For infinite-dimensional spaces, it's important to consider what type of basis you are using - Schauder, Hamel, etc.

Comment: @user3201708 So if the taylor series works well for a particular function, the method is applicable?

Comment: @Math1000 I suppose this comment is an answer to my question (2)?

Comment: You are confusing two rings: $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, while $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$ means the ring of power series.  Not every power series is a polynomial, so (1) is false.  Note also that while $1, x, x^2, \ldots$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$. The definition of basis requires that you can write every vector as a *finite* linear combination of the basis elements, but for general power series infinite linear combinations are required.  (But see generalized types of bases, as Math1000 mentions above.)

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks for your comment. But does that mean my whole idea is incorrect? Or just my understanding of the basis of the polynomial ring?

Comment: @YourongZang I am not sure.  Would need to think a bit more.

Comment: Note that not every smooth function is equal to its Taylor series; we would need to restrict our analysis to analytic functions

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure.