# Can this be a Schauder basis of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$

Tags: formal-power-series, schauder-basis, hamel-basis

A few hours ago, I asked a question about using Taylor expansion of two analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ to determine whether these two functions are linearly independent. Basically I was trying to express every analytic function as an element in $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$.

[The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440217/is-the-following-idea-rigorous)

A contributor commented that though $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,\dots\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$.

My question is, since $\forall a(x)\in\mathbb{R}[[x]]$, $\exists! \{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ s.t. $a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, isn't $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a Schauder basis of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$? Is the user referring to  Hamel bases when he says that it is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, those users are most likely referring to an algebraic basis. You mean Schauder basis with respect to what topology?

Comment: @Gae.S. Do you mean we need a norm topology for this basis? (Forgive me if this is a bad question, I am pretty new to these kinds of stuff.)

Comment: In my opinion, you need a topology even to give meaning to the expression $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, given that $x^n$ is just supposed to be some element of a vector space. However, you need a topological-vector-space structure (not necessarily a normable one, though) to make sense of a Schauder basis.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you. I will try to read more materials.

Comment: @Gae.S.  The expression $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ makes sense because it is the form that a general element of the ring of formal power series takes.  But it also makes sense as a convergent infinite sum of formal power series (thinking of each $a_nx^n$ as a separate formal power series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Schauder basis of a vector space $V$ over a field $k$ is a sequence $b_0,b_1,\ldots$ of vectors in $V$ such that every element of $V$ can be expressed uniquely as a convergent series of the form $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i b_i$ where each $a_i$ is in $k$.  For this to make any sense, there must be a topology on $V$ that gives meaning to the notion of convergence.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis .

For any field $k$, the ring $k[[x]]$ of formal power series is a vector space over $k$, and has a natural topology as the product of countably many copies of $k$, with the *discrete* topology on each.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series .

A sequence of formal power series converges if, for every $n$, the coefficient of $x^n$ stabilizes.  (That is, eventually, as we go further in the sequence, that coefficient never changes again.)

So:  Yes $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ is a perfectly good (Schauder) basis for $k[[x]]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and there should be a "_" between your sigma notation and $\{i=0\}$.

Comment: @YourongZang:  Thanks, I fixed that.